# How can I call function even before useState?

Tags: reactjs

I have a context state that contains that is on page UserState.js

```
data: null
columns: null
```

And I am calling it via useContext on UserTable.js

```
const userContext = useContext(UserContext);
const {data,columns} = userContext;
```

And for what is inside the data and columns, it will be extracted by calling API via axios.

I am facing difficulty is that, for the particular page, I also have a localData and localColumns that is

```
const [localColumns, setlocalColumns] = useState([...columns]);
const [localData, setlocalData] = useState([...data]);
```

Where because when calling it, the data is still null and hence it returns error.
I have tried extraction from the database using useEffect and/or useLayout

The overall file structure is like this

```
-src
--components
---context
----user
-----UserState.js
--pages
---UserPage
----UserTable.js
```

And the UserTable.js looks like this

```
const UserTable = () => {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    {
      getAllUser();
    }
  });

  const { data, columns,setAllUserFunc } = userContext;

  const getAllUser = () => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/v1/users", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + token.access.token,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        let allUser = response.data.results;
        let allNormalUser = allUser.filter((user) => user.role == "user");
        setAllUserFunc(allNormalUser);
      })
      .catch((error) => {});
  };

  const [localColumns, setlocalColumns] = useState([...columns]);
  const [localData, setlocalData] = useState([...data]);

  return (
      <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />
   )
}
```

The setAllUserFunc will set the data and columns to be their corresponding that is on the UserState.js and I confirm it is working (by commenting on the localData and localColumns as well as table).

My question is how can I call the function before the useState that set localColumns?

useEffect and useLayoutEffect don't work